# Turtlebot2/RGBDSLAM/kinetic

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the instructions in the [repo link](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2) to install rgbdslam dependencies when i did the command `rosdep install rgbdslam` , I got this error:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
rgbdslam: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [catkin]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391589/turtlebot2/rgbdslam/kinetic/) by [kemo007](https://answers.ros.org/users/87031/kemo007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-11-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-24**:
hi @kemo007. Sorry i edited your question a little, to ensure it's more readable.

`rosdep` is not an installation tool, it basically checks for missing dependencies. To install from source, please follow this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace

**Comment by [kemo007](https://answers.ros.org/users/87031/kemo007/) on 2021-11-24**:
@osilva thank you for editing. I already did this tutorial but I still got the same error. please any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this:

```
$ mkdir -p rgbdslam_ws/src
$ cd rgbdslam_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2.git
$ cd ..
$ catkin_make
```

If there are no errors when compiling, then source the package. If there are compiling errors, check the Issues in the repo to see how to solve them. If you still have issues please post another question with the error(s).

```
$ echo 'source ~/rgbdslam_ws/devel/setup.bash' >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

To test:

```
$ roslaunch rgbdslam openni+rgbdslam.launch
```

With regards to `rosdep error`, please refer to this prior answer that explains how `rosdep` works: https://answers.ros.org/question/320734/cannot-locate-rosdep-definition/

**Additional information:**
I installed a fresh Kinetic copy to test this repo from source.
I found 4 errors due to missing dependencies, addressed with, you will need to do this to get compilation to work.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-libg2o
$ sudo apt install ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-perception
$ sudo apt-get install libdevil1c2 libdevil-dev
$ sudo apt install ros-kinetic-openni*
```

Tested the launch file and it works but there is a connection error but don't have time now to check what is causing it. The installation portion works :) There is a lot of info under **Issues** section of the repo, so please look at it.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kemo007](https://answers.ros.org/users/87031/kemo007/) on 2021-11-26**:
@osilva, sorry, but I tried to do it again following ur instructions but still got the same error. Any others ideas. i have been trying to solve this issue for a long time.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-26**:
I don't understand how could you get the same error if I didn't use `rosdep` in the instructions on purpose. Not possible the error is the same. Anyways, try a fresh install, looks you have broken dependencies. The package builds ok. What OS are you using? Ubuntu 16.04?

**Comment by [kemo007](https://answers.ros.org/users/87031/kemo007/) on 2021-11-26**:
@osilva, ubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-26**:
Start a fresh ROS installation, don't install anything else until you compile RGBDA package.

After ROS installation, install the dependencies first:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-libg2o
$ sudo apt install ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-perception
$ sudo apt-get install libdevil1c2 libdevil-dev
$ sudo apt install ros-kinetic-openni*
```

Then proceed with the installation instructions as per answer. If you encounter issue, pls post the error.